# Does JPA over Hibernate maintain a pool of objects for entity beans like EJB does for stateless session beans?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I do know that EJB, and I guess Spring does the same, maintain a pool of instances of stateless session beans, my question is if JPA implemetations maintain a pool for Entity beans as well?

It seems to me that it could be useful when there is a need for retrieving a large quantity of instances as the instances would be polled form the pool instead of being create on demand. 
Any opinions on if it would have a major impact on big lists of objects are also welcome.

Comment: You are wrong. Spring doesn't maintain anything nor does JPA. Objection creation is pretty cheap and fast, and introducing the overhead of an object pool is creating more overhead then yu gain. It might have been a good idea with java 1.0 nowadays it isn't.

Comment: "Session" is nothing to do with JPA. JPA persists objects. This is all documented in the JPA spec or in the docs for JPA providers

Comment: M. Deinum. Yes, you're right, it was a question based in old information prior to ~2005 when JVMs did have some overhead on creating new objects.
Would you know any source where I could read exactly how it was improved?

Comment: M. Deinum. Can you put your explanation as answer plus this link of a small research over the subject that concludes that the object creation is yet not as trivial operation as an int increment for instance but that it has improved hugely from java 1.4 to 6 (an older), so, where nanosecond-level optimization really is relevant it is still a good idea avoid object creation, the pool than becomes something just used for external resources as database for instance.  

http://drmirror.net/2013/06/06/object-creation/ 

If you answer with all this, I'll consider the question answered.